# Unable to perform describe on certificate after installing cert-manager in kubernetes using stable helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I have installed cert manager according to the [documentation](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) using Helm. After installation I am able to get certificates using Ingress too. But after getting certificate I am unable to describe, delete to perform any other option on certificate or any other cert manager resources.
I get following error

```
kubectl describe certificate cert-name
Error from server: conversion webhook for cert-manager.io/v1alpha2, Kind=Certificate failed: Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/convert?timeout=30s: service "cert-manager-webhook" not found
```

How to fix this issue?

**Edit**
Including status of cert manager

```
NAME                                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/certs-cert-manager-6d96b77bd5-9jmpc              1/1     Running   0          3h13m
pod/certs-cert-manager-cainjector-7658745698-rrz2v   1/1     Running   0          3h13m
pod/certs-cert-manager-webhook-84f76cc797-49j99      1/1     Running   0          3h13m

NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/certs-cert-manager           ClusterIP   10.245.133.177   <none>        9402/TCP   69d
service/certs-cert-manager-webhook   ClusterIP   10.245.11.233    <none>        443/TCP    3h13m

NAME                                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/certs-cert-manager              1/1     1            1           69d
deployment.apps/certs-cert-manager-cainjector   1/1     1            1           69d
deployment.apps/certs-cert-manager-webhook      1/1     1            1           69d

NAME                                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/certs-cert-manager-5d66886cc               0         0         0       3h14m
replicaset.apps/certs-cert-manager-5f797cf4fc              0         0         0       69d
replicaset.apps/certs-cert-manager-6d96b77bd5              1         1         1       3h13m
replicaset.apps/certs-cert-manager-cainjector-7658745698   1         1         1       3h13m
replicaset.apps/certs-cert-manager-cainjector-9d7d6bb5b    0         0         0       69d
replicaset.apps/certs-cert-manager-webhook-7946b5dbbd      0         0         0       69d
replicaset.apps/certs-cert-manager-webhook-84f76cc797      1         1         1       3h13m
```

Comment: share status of all pods and service from certmnager's namespace

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu added the status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error it's looking for a service with name `cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager` but the service name is actually `certs-cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager`. I think while installing using helm you gave it some name other than `cert-manager` which may be causing the problem.

Use exactly the below commands without changing the name and see if that works.

```
# Helm v3+
$ helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --version v0.15.1 \
  # --set installCRDs=true

# Helm v2
$ helm install \
  --name cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --version v0.15.1 \
  jetstack/cert-manager \
  # --set installCRDs=true
```